# Is there a Japanese equivalent to the phrase, "when in Rome"?

Tags: idioms

Is there a Japanese equivalent to the phrase, "when in Rome"?

Comment: @virmaior I think the duplicate functionality is only supposed to be used when the question is a duplicate, not when the answer to this question can be found in another answer.

Answer (score 12):

Yes.

> [郷【ごう】に入【い】っては郷【ごう】に従【したが】え](http://kotowaza-allguide.com/ko/gouniittewagou.html)

which literally means "When you enter a village, obey (the custom of) the village".