# What is the difference between 都市 and 郷?

Tags: kanji

Do they mean the same thing? What situations should I use one over the other?

Comment: Could you explain where you've run across these terms and why you think they might be equivalent? They're almost opposite in meaning.

Comment: In a manga. It had 黄金郷 and 黄金都市 in similar contexts.

Comment: @BryanTan Oh, that's 郷【きょう】, not 郷【ごう】...

Comment: The manga didn't have hiragana, my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

都市 is a little stiff word that means "city" or "urban area". See: [What is the difference between 市, 都市, 都会 and 市街](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48973/5010)

郷【ごう】 is an uncommon word that roughly means "countryside", "country town", "town", etc. It's also a rare name suffix for small districts in some towns/villages. Practically speaking, you probably don't need this word outside of [this common idiom](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28530/5010).

**EDIT:** -郷【きょう】 is a rare suffix that roughly means "village" or "town". You would see it only in a few fixed compounds including [温泉郷](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%B8%A9%E6%B3%89%E9%83%B7).